# Python: Get script location

Tags: python, file, get

I've got a question.
How can a program get its own location?
For example, I've got a script ("script.py") on a path ("C:\Programs\script.py").
I want a function, which gives me the path. Like the following:

```
scriptdic() ==> "C:/programs/"
```

Thanks for coming answers.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick. . .

```
import os.path
import sys

os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It's exactly what I wanted,,, or in my case os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+"/"